# Is there an nginx variable for the unresolved upstream server address?

Tags: nginx

When using nginx as a reverse proxy to a group of servers in an upstream block, is there a variable that corresponds to the unresolved server name? For example, consider the following configuration:

```
http {
    upstream foo {
        server foo1.example.com:8080;
        server foo1.example.com:8081;
        server foo2.example.com:8080;
        server foo2.example.com:8081;
    }
    server {
        server_name foo.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://foo;
        }
    }
}
```

Let `foo.example.com`, `foo1.example.com`, and `foo2.example.com` be defined names that resolve to 192.0.2.1, 192.0.2.2, and 192.0.2.3 respectively.

Suppose a request comes in for `foo.example.com` and nginx decides to choose `foo2.example.com` port 8080 as the upstream server and the request succeeds. Then, to my knowledge, these will be the values of some relevant variables:

- `$host = foo.example.com`
- `$proxy_host = foo`
- `$upstream_addr = 192.0.2.3:8080` (*)

However, none of these match the value given in the configuration for the upstream server. So, more specifically, my question is: which variable, if any, will have the value of `foo2.example.com:8080` in this case?

To avoid the X-Y problem, these are the things I'm trying to accomplish:

1. to log the upstream server by hostname rather than by IP address, since resolved IP address may be temporary or may not support 1:1 reverse lookup
2. to `map` the upstream server to another piece of information that's more useful, also for logging purposes
3. to configure hostname verification (e.g., via `proxy_ssl_name`) for upstream SSL when the servers don't share the same certificate (this might warrant a question of its own, but it's not the only use case)

(*) = The variable `$upstream_addr` does not seem to be available at all stages of the request, e.g. adding `proxy_set_header Upstream-Addr $upstream_addr;` to the location block seems to have no effect, implying the variable is empty

Answer (score -2):

Proxies can be tricky. Nginx's `proxy_set_header` is what you want. [Nginx Docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)

```
proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
```

Look here [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848406/3950986) of a more detailed config for proxies

Comment: I don't think this is addressing the question I'm asking. As I already noted, the value of the `$host` variable is not useful here. This is also not about an issue with the upstream server getting the right headers, but rather about getting better diagnostics out of nginx itself.